# Generically create object in Javascript from a string class name

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create an object in Javascript generically from a string class name similar to Java? Maybe some type of Factory?

I want a database to hold a list of class names. Each class name will be associated with a user friendly name. These user friendly names would populate a menu. When a user selects a menu item, the respective class name will be retrieved and the class (object) created. I currently do something similar in Java.

For example, instead of

var obj = new demo.view.CustomObject({});

I would like something like this

var obj = Factory.create('demo.view.CustomObject', params);

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object properties using a string. Here I have created a factory method that splits the string by dot. Then using [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) I get into the `constructor` function and finally create the object.

```
function construct(constructorPath, params) {
  var constructorFunc = constructorPath.split('.')
    .reduce((prev, next) => prev[next], window)
  return new constructorFunc(params)
}

// Usage:
var obj = construct('demo.view.CustomObject', someParams)
```

Comment: Awesome. Nicely done. Fits the bill perfectly. Thank you.